# Not able to PUBLISH Visual Studio solution files from Teamcity

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild, teamcity

I am using Teamcity with MSBuild to build my .NET application (Has three components : **Daemon, MVC, WCF**). Once, I build it, the corresponding application gets built and placed as a PACKAGE on an agent machine. When I navigate over to the location, I can see the application with all the sub folders. And inside each of the component folder is its corresponding Visual Studio solution file.

***Now comes the question***:

I really want to know how to PUBLISH these three solution files directly from Teamcity. My plan is, once I publish, I ll transfer the published files onto the target server and thereby host it on IIS.

I have tried almost all the possible ways to make it publish, but nothing works. Even tried adding a Visual Studio (sln) build runner to all the individual solution files from Teamcity , with the below command line parameters:

**/Property:Configuration="ActivityManager.sln" /Property:DeployOnBuild=true /Property:PublishProfile="ActivityManager.sln" /Property:_PackageTempDir="..\ActivityManager\Publish"**

This DOES NOT work.And says

> ***"MSBuild command line parameters contain "/property:" or "/p:". It is recommended to define System Property on Build Parameters "***

Later tried this in the Command line parameter:

**/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=DotNet /p:_PackageTempDir="..\ActivityManager\Publish"**

This publishes only one of the solution files. And doesn't work for the others. Or an error says ***

> ***Deployment Unpublishable***

---

Please help !!!

Answer (score 0):

Change directory to where your solution file is and execute the following command for deploying.

```
  C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MSBuild\\12.0\\Bin\\msbuild.exe SOLUTION.sln /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:PublishProfile=PUBLISHING_PROFILE.pubxml /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True /p:UserName=USERNAME_OF_SERVER /p:Password=PASSWORD
```

This worked for me.

You can use a command line build step.